# Repeat Row Totals in a Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have created a Matrix as below. It shows the score for each month. Now I want to created another row to display the Row total in each cell (please see the table). I appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you

```html
      M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7
Score 10 12 14 16 8  4 14
Total 78 78 78 78 78 78 78
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just need to sum every `Score` in the dataset then you can do this

```
=SUM(Fields!Score.Value, "MyDatasetName")
```

This simply says "Sum every Score with in the scope of the entire dataset called MyDatasetName". By default a SUM would only have scope with in the current column group and/or rowgroup but by specifying the scope as the dataset name we are overriding that.

**Note** The dataset name is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, the syntax you gave provides the Grand total of different "score" types e.g.score, score1, score2...I have already filtered the Row just for "score". So I need the Row total value to be filtered for the score type.Thanks.

Comment: You need to edit your question to show sample data and your report design. Your current sample shows score by month and a total, so that's all I could base my answer on.